# Fourier transform and sketches

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm really having trouble with these types of questions and the solutions provided are quite vague. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Q: Let $\delta_n(x)=(n\pi^{-\frac{1}{2}})e^{-n^2x^2}$. Find it's Fourier transform $\widetilde{\delta}_n(k)$. 
Sketch $\delta_n(x)$ & $\widetilde{\delta}_n(k)$ for small and large $n$ & comment on their behaviour.

Sorry for the poor formatting, hope it makes sense!

Comment: It will help to look up the Gaussian distribution and it's Fourier transform.